# Is it possible to use sql-connect in the open-source version of Saxon XSLT?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I am trying to use the **sql-connect** statement of **Saxon** to access a data-mapping that is saved in my database to perform an XML transformation.

I read in the boook "XSLT" by Doug Tidwell (page 334), the following:
"To complicate things further, the username must match the name of the database schema."

Does that mean, I cannot have username and database schema name different when using the open source version of Saxon? Or would that be possible somehow?

Also would I include both *saxon9.jar* and *saxon9-sql.jar* into my Java program to make it work?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Michael Kay from the Saxon-mailing list:

"The SQL extension makes use of the 'element extensibility' mechanism, which is only available in Saxon-PE and higher.

However, the code of the SQL extension itself is open source, so you are free to modify and extend it. In other words, it's an open source plug-in to a commercial product. This might explain why you have seen apparently conflicting information."

So the answer is: No. Without a license, the element extensibility cannot be used.

Answer (score -1):

This is in fact possible and something I have been using for years. You must either compile the saxon-sql.jar from source or find a jar and download it (e.g. [http://www.java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/saxon.htm)). Place it in the same directory as your compatible saxon.jar (Saxon HE works fine) and you can use it after including the saxon namespaces

```
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
xmlns:sql="java:/net.sf.saxon.sql.SQLElementFactory"
extension-element-prefixes="saxon sql"
```

in your stylesheet tag.